# How to model a Firebase Database in UML diagrams?

Tags: android, firebase, nosql, uml, class-diagram

I have a project in android so I decided to make a Quiz app, and I used Firebase in it. 
But I also need to design UML diagrams for this project and I was wondering if I can do it since Firebase is a Table-less database.

Comment: What exactly is your concern? Do you wonder if you can represent a Firebase DB in UML?

Comment: @Thomas Kilian yes because I have a university project and they need our android app to be represented in UML diagrams and I used Firebase till now so I was wodering if I can do it

Comment: A conceptual model is definitely possible, for example in a class diagram. A more concrete model may be possible, depending on your exact data model. For an introduction and some samples, see https://www.ripublication.com/ijaer17/ijaerv12n5_12.pdf. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323841/mongodb-how-to-represent-a-schema-diagram-in-a-thesis

Comment: Please refer to the links @FrankvanPuffelen gave to you. Next time please be more concrete in your question. I had voted this as unclear. I will not retract my close vote since as such it is too broad.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okay Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase) databases, be it its [realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or the [cloud firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), are [document-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) [NoSQL](https://hostingdata.co.uk/nosql-database/) databases. There are indeed no tables, just collections of documents, where each document is a JSON-like structure, and documents could contain other embedded collections or documents.

**In theory**, each document in a collection could be completely different from all the others. In this case, an UML class-diagram would make no sense since classes suppose common properties and behaviors.

```
db.collection("ouch"):          // Not recommended 
     [ {name: "Spiderman"}, 
       {size: "XXL", item: "T-Shirt}, 
       {date: "July 4 1776", event:"independence day"} ]
```

**In practice**, however, documents in a collection are in general  a set of very similar objects, or at least related objects. May be one object of the set has a couple of properties more, or a couple of properties less. But they represent the same kind of things:

```
db.collection("users"):   // example 1, small variations
      [ { id: "AL", first: "Ada",last: "Lovelace"},
        { id: "JSMITH", last: "Smith", first: "Joe", lastLogin:"2021-07-10"} ]

db.collection("shopItems"):    // example 2, more variations but common ground
      [ { id: 123, type: "Book", title: "The definitive guide to Firebase", author:"L.Moroney", price: 34.23 },
        { id: 124, type: "Record", title: "Get lucky", artist: "Daft Punk", price: 16.20}
        { id: 125, type: "Shirt", brand: "Seidensticker", model:"Classic", size: "XL", color:"white", price: 65.00 } ]
```

In this case, you may perfectly use UML class diagrams, because UML is not table based,  but class based:

- A class represents a kind of things.  In reverse engineering you'd usually start with the known collections.
- Small structural differences between documents of a same kind would be represented in the UML class diagram either with "optional" properties (i.e. multiplicity [0..1]) (see `lastLogin` in the `users` example).
- More substantial differences between documents having some common ground, would usually be modeeled with more specialized classes (see the `shopItems` example, where we can guess a class `ShopItem` and specializations thereof such as `BookItem`, `RecordItem`, `TextileItem`).
- The challenge in the modelling, is to understand the embedded documents and sub-collections.  These are often sign other associated classes (or composed classes).

In principle, the UML class-diagram would not be used only for the database (data only), but it would be used to design the **objet model** of your application (data and behavior) independently of your database. The model could then [help you to design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67532753/3723423) the database based on the kind of objects needed to address you' user's needs.

Comment: "In theory, each document in a collection can be completely different from all the others." ... that's the worst practice ever. no one would never recommend that. Data persistence = 0 ... And you should always do a conceptual model of your data (yes with uml), imho.

Comment: @BorisDetry Exactly!  I think we fully agree. This is why I started the sentence with “In theory” and followed with a paragraph “In practice” for the real world. And my last paragraph says exactly what you say about the conceptual model, except that O stringly believe that the conceptual model is not just for data, but for classes (data+behavior) ;-)