# How to draw a NoSQL database (document oriented) with UML?

Tags: database, nosql, uml

I'm beginner in the use of NoSQL and aim to build a uber-like database. Is it possible to draw a CouchDB database (document oriented) with UML and in particular, how to do joins? Or is there another alternative better suited for NoSQL database modeling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **UML class diagrams** to model entities and aggregates of an application domain, regardless of the implementation technology.
You can also model a more concrete implementation that uses a [NoSQL](https://hostingdata.co.uk/nosql-database/) database, and in particular [document stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) such as CouchDB.  Objects are stored in the database are kind-of dehydrated (i.e. object data without their behavior) into a document.

There are challenge that you will face:

1. mapping between the [document](https://guide.couchdb.org/draft/documents.html) world and the object world:  a **document may contain several related objects** (no joins needed), as well as **links to other objects** (see also [embedded/nested document  vs. document references](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/413088/209774)).
2. potentially **unstructured (or loosely structured) documents**: document databases are extremely flexible about the content of documents, and it is perfectly allowed to mix objects of completely unrelated classes into the same document collection.  Moreover, the fields/properties/members of a document may be dynamic and evolve.  In practice however, collections often contain similar objects that will vary mainly regarding the fields (for example to acknowledge existence of implicit classes). [Documents may even be validated according to a schema](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/401191/is-it-recommended-to-use-schemas-on-non-relational-databases/401193#401193) to ensure consistency if needed.
3. UML classes are based on strong typing, whereas types in documents are as flexible as the rest of their content (e.g. a field `from` could be a date `2000-04-02` in one document or a string `"a long time ago"` in another one).

So before you start, you need to think of the **mapping strategy**.  My advice would be to focus in UML on the design of your object model, and think of documents as a convenient grouping of related ones ([DDD aggregates](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) may help in this regard).  The following rule of thumb may help for the modeling:

- joins (e.g. links between independent documents) will be represented by associations.
- systematic grouping of objects with other, may suggest existence of some kind of stronger relation such as UML composition.
- fields that vary from document to document would be represented either with optional properties (multiplicity `0..1` or `0..*`) or generalisation/specialization of the enclosing object, depending on the logic that explains the variation.