# How can we build ER diagram and class diagram for project which uses firebase(NoSQL) as storage?

Tags: firebase, nosql, class-diagram, erd, srs

I am confused about how to make ER diagram or class diagram for Firebase which is NoSQL and there is no schema. And everything is stored here as  parent and child node. So Do I need to make the same ER diagram as for SQL databases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a NoSQL database (document oriented) with UML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67531751/how-to-draw-a-nosql-database-document-oriented-with-uml) - Because Firestore and and Firebase RealtimeDB appear to be document databases and most of the answer is about UML class diagrams, but could be transposed to ER